# S3 performance for LIST by prefix with millions of objects in a single bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a project where there will be about 80 million objects in an S3 bucket.  Every day, I will be deleting about 4 million and adding 4 million.  The object names will be in a pseudo directory structure:

```
/012345/0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
```

For deletion, I will need to list all objects with a prefix of `012345/`, and then delete them.  I am concerned of the time it will take for this LIST operation.  While it seems clear that S3's access time for individual assets does not increase for individual objects, I haven't found anything definitive that says that a LIST operation over 80MM objects, searching for 10 objects that all have the same prefix will remain fast in such a large bucket.

In a [side comment on a question about the maximum number of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394505/362536) that can be stored in a bucket (from 2008):

> In my experience, LIST operations do take (linearly) longer as object count increases, but this is probably a symptom of the increased I/O required on the Amazon servers, and down the wire to your client.

From the [Amazon S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html):

> There is no limit to the number of objects that can be stored in a bucket and no difference in performance whether you use many buckets or just a few. You can store all of your objects in a single bucket, or you can organize them across several buckets.

While I am inclined to believe the Amazon documentation, it isn't entirely clear what operations their comment is directed to.

Before committing to this expensive plan, I would like to definitively know if LIST operations when searching by prefix remain fast when buckets contain millions of objects.  If someone has real-world experience with such large buckets, I would love to hear your input.

Comment: Hey, 2 years passed since your question.
Can you tell if you made the system in the end using S3 list by prefix and how did it perform?

Comment: @KaplanIlya I did end up using prefix, but I don't remember how well it did.  Sorry!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prefix searches are fast, if you've  chosen the prefixes correctly. Here's an explanation: https://cloudnative.io/blog/2015/01/aws-s3-performance-tuning/

Comment: don't know why this doesn't have more upvotes, it specifically speaks to the question and addresses OP's issue, even at 80m + records (although I'd additionally look at an object-retirement strategy)

Comment: @MrMesees because my answer was 3 years late :)

Comment: @MrMesees and because they suggested solution is exactly what the other answer already points to; keep an index somewhere else.

Comment: The original link is dead, an archived version is available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160327092959/http://cloudnative.io/blog/2015/01/aws-s3-performance-tuning/

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen a problem, but why would you ever list a million files just to pull a few files out of the list? It's not S3 performance, it's likely do to the call just taking longer.

Why not store the file names in a database, index them, then query from there. That'd be a better solution I'd think.

Comment: It's a valid question, and an option I am considering for a future enhancement.  Unfortunately right now, the system creating objects on S3 has no knowledge of the database and cannot connect to it.  There is a system (made up of a bunch of legacy Perl scripts I'm drastically trying to kill off) which uploads an original asset to S3.  From there, another system will create derived assets (resized, cropped, and re-compressed photos) on-the-fly and uploads the derived versions to S3 in this pseudo directory structure.  The only way around this is to have yet another database to keep track of....

Comment: ... the derived assets, but if S3 is fast enough with its list operations, there would be no need for that other database.

Comment: I think parsing the list would be much slower than the speed S3 provides it to you. So I suspect you'd be ok. I haven't dealt with a size that big, but I doubt amazon is lying here. We have many directories that are larger than best practices for other filesystems that work really badly, but in S3 work great.

Comment: To be clear, I'm talking about listing objects by prefix, so S3 is only going to return those 4 or 5 objects with the prefix I've specified.  And, I don't think Amazon is lying, it's just that at that point in the documentation it seems to be talking about getting and putting objects, not necessarily listing by prefix.

Comment: in that case I can't imagine there being any kind of noticeable performance hit. If there is, I think posting the the aws forums would be in order. You might even email your sales manager or a ticket informing them you will be doing this. That might help them guarantee the performance for you.