# Scala data reading from Amazon S3

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been struggling reading nested folders stored on one of bucket on S3, using Scala.
I wrote script with my credentials. In bucket - there are many folders. Let say one folder name is "folder1". In this folder there are many subfolders and so on. I want to get names of each subfolder(any each inside them) for folder1.

```
val yourAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)   
val amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(yourAWSCredentials)

print(amazonS3Client.listObjects(bucketName,"folder1").getObjectSummaries())
```

But this returns not the structure I need. May be there is easier way to get the path?

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: Current output is just an address of object. Not the real folders and names. If I move further like getObjectSummaries().get(1).getKey then I get some path. But its end file of last subdirectory. and if I change 2, its not in order as in usual file structure on disk. Thats why am unable to use looping with different indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is not a regular hierarchical file system. It does not actually have folders.

You need to understand S3 prefixes and delimiters. See [Listing Keys Hierarchically Using a Prefix and Delimiter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html).

Also see [Max files per directory in S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394198/max-files-per-directory-in-s3).